# Split a unicode string without regular expression

Tags: string, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to  split  a  Unicode string to it all possible splits

This code will give all character permutation 
in English string, but not in unicode

```
def allperm(inputstr):
        for i in range(len(inputstr)):
            yield(inputstr[i])        
            for s in allperm(inputstr[:i] + inputstr[i+1:]):
                yield(inputstr[i] + s)
```

For example,

```
സമരക്കാര്‍ക്കാരുടെ 
സമ #രക്കാര്‍ക്കാരുടെ 
സമര#ക്കാര്‍ക്കാരുടെ 
സമരക്കാ#ര്‍ക്കാരുടെ
```

For example in English

```
running can be sliced to

ru # nning
run #ning
runn#ing
```

This Unicode string need to be sliced in all of its  character combinations

I know `string.split()`and `import re`

Is there any way to split it other than these two methods ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "all possible splits" and why you're looking for a possible alternative to those two methods?

Comment: I need to split the the word to all combinations using methods rather than regular expression and split method

Comment: @karu: Please provide a sample output. Your Question as it stands now is difficult to understand.

Comment: @karu what is a "combination" - can you provide examples? You mention both splitting and slicing - which are different operations, and "combinations" which is (generally) something different again...

Comment: Are you asking how to get the prefixes of unicode strings, or how to split a unicode string into two at a certain index?

Comment: @Karu you can [edit] your question to include that code (so it's readable unlike in a comment) with a sentence explaining if you're experiencing issues with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use byte slicing, e.g.

```
 a = "സമരക്കാര്‍ക്കാരുടെ".encode('utf-8')
 a
=> '\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb8\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xae\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb0\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\x95\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb5\xc2\x8d\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\x95\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb0\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb5\xc2\x8d\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x8d\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\x95\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb5\xc2\x8d\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\x95\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\xb0\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb5\xc2\x81\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb4\xc2\x9f\xc3\xa0\xc2\xb5\xc2\x86' 
 a[:2]
=> '\cx3\xa0'
 a[2:4]
=> '\xc2\xb4'
```

Also recommended reading: http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @DavidKernin Ok let me try